# Transparency is rendered incorrectly in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, color

I've found that images with transparency are rendered incorrectly in Blender.

I have a gradient that starts from black and fades to transparent as follows:

[image: Transparent gradient]

In normal image editors, the gradient looks like this over a white background:

[image: Normal gradient]

As you can see, the gradient transitions smoothly from left to right as expected.

In Blender's compositor, however, the same gradient over a white background looks like this:

[image: Wrong gradient]

It seems like Blender is treating the transparency of the image incorrectly, the colors do not transition smoothly from left to right. I've tried using both the Mix and Alpha Over nodes, they produce the same result. I am using Blender 3.0.1.

What is causing this, and how do I fix Blender's compositing to display transparency as expected?

Comment: Hi :). If you're using 'Filmic' color transform, the white won't be 100%. Switching color transform to 'standard' should solve it.

Comment: That doesn't solve it unfortunately, the overall image got slightly brighter, but it's still wildly different from the behaviour in image editors.